# How to create a custom field formula to show task owner first name on the task object?

Tags: formula, formula-field, tasks, custom

Current formula which is getting an error:
[image]

Comment: Can you check this formula`Owner:User.FirstName`

Comment: thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I have updated same as answer as well. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The API name of the `Assigned To` is `Owner`. So can you try the below formula.

```
Owner:User.FirstName
```